# Avoid duplicating fields for different forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I've run into this on three projects now.  I have multiple forms that reference the same data fields, but have different displays.  For the example below I am updating or referencing the AspNetUser table from create new user, edit profile, login etc.  If I try for a single base view model I have issues with required fields.

So for example here are the fields for Username and Password/confirmation

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9$$!%*#-_?&]*$", ErrorMessage = "The user name is invalid. Only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores are allowed.")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{7,20}$",
    ErrorMessage = "Password must contain a number, a lowercase character, an uppercase character, a special character and be between 7 and 20 characters in length.")]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Obviously from the login screen I don't need confirm password.  From the edit profile page you cannot update the username.  **I hate having the same code in multiple places and I don't want to go into a bunch of viewmodels to update regular expressions if the rules for password or username change.**

Someone have a good way to handle this?

Comment: Just to be clear on what you are saying, is this when you have another view and on that view you do not render  ConfirmPassword but when you submit the form it does not validate because this field  ConfirmPassword is required. ?

Comment: Why don't you use class inheritance that way you can have specific models that inherit from base class that would only have lets say password and not confirm, and another model can inherit from both.

Comment: As always, view model are the solution. As for you concerns about the updating multiple regular expressions, create validation attributes that inherit `RegularExpressionAttribute` and contains the expression, for example `PasswordAttribute` (so there is only one piece of code to update)

Comment: Don't use `string` for passwords. Use `SecureString`.

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke.  Multiple view models are the way to go, and if you need a common validation attribute, it's easy to write a custom one.  I'd also avoid class inheritance.  You can end up with complex class hierarchies that cause you trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I am happy with.  I create an interface with the fields that have the complex validation then I use MetadataType to utilize it in specific ViewModels.

```
interface IUserBase
{

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9$$!%*_\-#?&]*$", ErrorMessage = "The user name is invalid. Only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores are allowed.")]
    string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{7,20}$",
        ErrorMessage = "Password must contain a number, a lowercase character, an uppercase character, a special character and be between 7 and 20 characters in length.")]
    string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Then any view model that utilizes UserName, Password, or ConfirmPassword get setup as below.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IUserBase))]
public class NewUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

I kept the display name of password out of the interface so that I can call it *New Password* when editing a user but *Password* when creating a user.